# foldergrid php client get folder info

Tags: php, grid, client, directory

I am trying to implement a simple foldergrid php client.  I am using the simple php client from the foldergrid api documentation.  The client code that I got from the api documentation is:

```
class FolderGridClient {
     protected $_cookieFileLocation = './cookie.txt';
     public $_webpage;
     public $_status;
     public $_location;

    const SERVER_HOST = 'https://secure.foldergrid.com';

    public function authenticate($username,$password, $domain){
        $params = array("domain"=>$domain,"username"=>$username,"password"=>$password);
        $this->createCurl(self::SERVER_HOST."/login",$params);
    }
    public function createDomain($adminemail,$adminpassword, $domainname, $adminfname, $adminlname){
        $json = json_encode( array('invite'=>true, 'admin' => array('email'=>$adminemail,'password'=>$adminpassword,'firstname'=>$adminfname,'lastname'=>$adminlname) ) );
        $this->createCurl(self::SERVER_HOST."/domain/".$domainname,$json,true);
    }
    public function uploadFile($file,$name,$parentDuid) {
        $fh = fopen($file, "rb");
        if($fh) {
            $json = json_encode( array('parentDuid'=>$parentDuid, 'name' => $name, 'parts' => 1) );
            $this->createCurl(self::SERVER_HOST."/file/provision",$json,true);

            if($this->_location){
                $headers = array(
                        'fg-eap: false',
                        'fg-md5:'.md5_file($file),
                        'Content-Type: binary/octet-stream'
                );

                $curl = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_PUT,true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_location);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($file));
                curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );

                $this->_webpage = curl_exec($curl);
                $this->_status = curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                fclose($fh);
                curl_close($curl);
            }
        }else{
            echo "File not found: $file \n";
        }
    }
    public function fetchFolder($pathOrDuid){
        $this->createCurl(self::SERVER_HOST."/folder/$pathOrDuid");
        return $this->_webpage;
    }
    public function fetchFile($fileid){
        $this->createCurl(self::SERVER_HOST."/file/$fileid");
        return $this->_webpage;
    }

    public function createCurl($url,$postFields = null, $put = false)
     {
         $s = curl_init();

         curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
         curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
         curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
         curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
         curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,false);
         curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$this->_cookieFileLocation);
         curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$this->_cookieFileLocation);

         if($postFields)
         {
             curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POST,true);
             if($put) {
                curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($postFields)));
                curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
             }else{
                curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
             }
             curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postFields);
         }
         $this->_webpage = curl_exec($s);
         $this->_status = curl_getinfo($s,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $this->_webpage, $matches);
         $this->_location = !empty($matches[1]) ? trim($matches[1][0]) : null;
         curl_close($s);
     }

}
```

Using this client, I was able to successfully upload a file to my folder grid root folder.  Now I have created a test folder under the root, and I am trying to use the API to get the duid of the folder.  I used the following code:

```
$uname='myuname';
$pwd='mypwd';
$domain='mydomain';
$rootDUID='duidOFRootFolder';

$client = new FolderGridClient;
$client->authenticate( $uname,$pwd,$domain);
if($client->_status < 400){
  echo "fetchFolder: " . $client->fetchFolder($domain.'/TestNewFolder') . "<BR>";
}
```

TestNewFolder is the name of the folder I created using the foldergrid javascript reference client at https://mydomain.foldergrid.com/show/*.html

The root foldername is the same as my domain name, which i think is standard for foldergrid.

However, when I run that code, I always get a folder not found response.  I have tried various different permutations of the folder path as an input to the fetchFolder function with no success.  so two questions:
1. how should I use the fetchFolder function in the php simple client to get the folder info - specifically the duid.
2. Does anyone have an addition to the php simple client to create a sub folder, once I have discovered the duid of the target folder?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

When you [create a new folder programmatically using the FolderGrid API](http://foldergrid.com/api/index.html#create-or-update-a-folder) you assign the immutable DUID which uniquely identifies that folder. One easy method to determine the DUID for any existing folder is to simply open the FolderGrid Web App and right click the folder to choose "Show Info".

To determine an unknown DUID programmatically using API calls, you simply traverse the folder path from a higher folder with a known DUID using calls to [Show Folder Details](http://foldergrid.com/api/index.html#show-folder-details) which display the DUIDs of all subfolders. For example, you would execute a GET /folder/DUID on your root folder which will return (among other things) a json array of the names and DUIDs of all the subfolders of your root folder - including TestNewFolder

One useful shortcut is mentioned in the API docs for [Show Folder Details](http://foldergrid.com/api/index.html#show-folder-details) which is that you can substitute asterisk '*' for DUID in that call as a shorthand reference to the root folder.

The sample PHP client code uses the name "pathOrDuid" for the parameter to fetchFolder but that's misleading because the call to retrieve a [folder's details by path is a distinct call as documented here](http://foldergrid.com/api/index.html#show-folder-details-by-path).

Answer (score 0):

So following Simmerman's suggestions, here is some php code that I used to get the duid of a sub folder if I know the parent folders duid (like '*' for the root folder).  I have added the following function to the php simple client that foldergrid provided in their documentation:

```
public function getSubFolderDuid($parentDuid,$folderName) {
  $fetchParent = $this->fetchFolder($parentDuid);

  $parentJsonMatch = array();
  preg_match("/\{.*\}/",$fetchParent,&$parentJsonMatch);
  $returnArray=true;
  $parentJsonArray = json_decode($parentJsonMatch[0],$returnArray);
  $subFolders = $parentJsonArray['folders'];

  foreach($subFolders as $folderData) {
    if ($folderData['name'] == $folderName) return $folderData['duid'];
  }

  return '';

}
```

obviously there is plenty of room to add error handling to this function in case the parent folder is not returned.  This function is assuming the parent folder exists and is returned as json data.

Here is the code I used to call the function:

```
    if($client->_status < 400){
      $parentDuid = '*';
      $folderName = 'TestNewFolder';
      $folderDuid = $client->getSubFolderDuid($parentDuid,$folderName);

      echo "$folderName:  $folderDuid<br>";
    }
```

With these building blocks I can now build code to traverse the directory tree or find a specific folder duid at an arbitrary depth in the tree.

Thanks for the pointing me in the right direction Simmerman